# "error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable" when I swap my Staging and Production deployments on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-web-roles

Every time I swap my deployments between Staging and Production, I got this kind of error :

> [Wed Oct 09 18:43:51.9519 +00:00 2013] [Error] [Zappiti.BaseApi] An
>   error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
>   details.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error
>   occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
>   details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has
>   occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session
>   Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, UInt32 error)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
>   ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>
> at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator
>   translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>
> at Zappiti.BaseApi.PutVideo(PutVideo putVideo, Guid userId, String
>   queueName, Boolean isBeta)

I deploy my package using a standard Build Definition from TFS.

Is there a way to avoid these connection errors ?

Comment: I get the same error, did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Me too - it's annoying.  Any insight?

Comment: So far, I use a try/catch to retry SaveChanges() that failed. I retry x times, with a sleep beteween each try. Not perfect, but it solve 90% of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this feature in the changelog of EF 6.x :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835

I'll take a try.

Stay tuned.